# Return Value from Java Thread Class

Tags: java, multithreading

So below is a simple Java class using multithreading, and my question is, is there a way for me to store the randomNumber from each thread (maybe in a variable called randomNumberOne or randomNumberTwo), so that I can use those to possibly get the sum of both and return it? 
I know this example sounds stupid but basically with my real code I am returning a value from each of my threads and want to get the average of them. I haven't found any solution for returning values in threads in java (also I am new to multithreading completely).

```
public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    MathThread one = new MathThread();
    MathThread two = new MathThread();

    one.start();
    two.start();
  }
}

class MathThread extends Thread{
   public MathThread(){
   }

public void run(){
    Random rand = new Random();

    int randomNumber = rand.nextInt((100 - 1) + 1) + 1;
    System.out.println(randomNumber);
}
```

Output

```
5
33
```

Comment: You can use `callables` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html.

Answer (score 3):

Add a result variable to your `MathThread` class and get the value after you `join` the thread:

```
class MathThread extends Thread
{
    private int result;
    public int getResult()
    { 
       this.join();
       return result;
    }

    public void run()
    {
       // ...

       result = randomNumber;
    }
}

one.start();
two.start();

double average = (one.getResult() + two.getResult()) / 2.0;
```

Comment: I know this is a really basic example, and your answer does answer the question at hand, but it does lead the op down a slippery slope. There is no error handling, for example. The same thing could be achieved through the use Callable and an Executor, for example, which, via the Future, would provide more information about the state of the calculation (if it fails, was cancelled, etc) - just saying ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can do

```
IntStream.of(0, 2).parallel()
         .map(i -> new Random().nextInt(100)+1)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Without using the Stream API you can do

```
List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    futures.add(ForkJoinPool.commonPool()
                            .submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
                                public Integer call() {
                                   return new Random().nextInt(100)+1;
                                }));
for(Future<Integer> future : futures)
   System.out.printl(future.get());
```

Comment: Could you give a brief explanation of each, or at least link to the relevant documentation? As it is, it's just code that can be plugged in, not code that can be understood and reused.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - Have you tried reading the Oracle Tutorial material on Java 8 Streams?

Comment: @StephenC I have, but the point is that answers should be enough to get the person started at least, instead of having to link to an outside thing for it to be more than just a chunk of code.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - How about you write a better answer yourself?   I notice you haven't answered a question in the last 7 days.  >>My point<< is that you will add more value to the site by contributing answers than by lobbing "advice" from the peanut gallery.

Comment: @StephenC I would write a better answer if I was halfway-decent at writing them :P Besides, it'd be pretty much identical to yours, but with one paragraph tacked on to the end.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - 1) it is not my answer.  2) Get half-way decent at writing!  It only takes practice.  3) This is a good place to practice.

Comment: @StephenC With regards to the first, shhhhh let me embarrass myself dangit. For the third, this really isn't, because either way my answer would be pretty much this with an extra paragraph. With regards to the second, I'm tryiiiing :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple snippet to customize:

```
// 1. Create and fill callables to execute
List<Callable<Integer>> callables = new LinkedList<>(); 
// callabels.addAll(makeMeCallables());

// 2. Run using Executor of your choice
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<Future<Integer>> results = service.invokeAll(callables);

// 3. Get the results 
if (results.get(i).isDone()) {
    Future f = result.get(i);   
    // process f.get()
}
```